# jQuery UI Spinner - Remove blue border

Tags: jquery-ui

I have the following jQuery spinner:

[image]

I'd like to remove the blue border that appears when the input control has the focus but, after examining the jquery-ui.css file, I can't find the CSS that controls this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the outline added by Chrome's user agent style sheet:

```
:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

You can remove it by specifying a value for the outline:

```
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: 0px; /* add this bit */
}
```

Comment: Wow, I am impressed! Very nice. Thank you.